# Saml Integration in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4, saml

I am using ASP.NET and Duende Identity Server to manage authentication. While Identity Server already implements a way to dynamically add an OIDC provider at runtime, I am now attempting to achieve a similar feature with a SAML provider. However, I have not been able to find a solution for this yet.

Comment: Maybe that tutorial can help you https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp

Answer (score 1):

The ComponentSpace SAML library supports adding SAML support to Identity Server. I suggest taking a look at our [Identity Server Integration Guide](https://www.componentspace.com/documentation/saml-for-asp-net-core/integrations/ComponentSpace%20IdentityServer4%20Integration%20Guide.pdf).

We also include an example Identity Server project with SAML support. An OIDC client can authenticate to Identity Server which then uses our SAML library to delegate authentication to an external identity provider using SAML SSO.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for ComponentSpace. I've used it a lot.

Also, this is a [SAML plugin](https://www.identityserver.com/products/saml2p) for Duende.